# Can I change MySQL decimal precision on the fly?

Tags: mysql

I'm in need of allowing larger numbers in my Rails application. Is it safe to just change the decimal column from :precision => 10, :scale => 4 to :precision => 11, :scale => 4 without any interference on the existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did it and it seems to be working, case closed.